# setting text in tableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, textfield

I want to programatically set a text in my UITableView. I do not want to do it from

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

I tried something like

```
[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0]].textField.text = @"test";
```

This doesn't work as this is not part of the structure. How do I do it? Been looking in the docs but cannot find it.

Comment: Why do you not want to do it in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method?

Comment: I want to load my tableView with data from ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate. So I thought it is easy to just set my tableView.textField.text from the ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate.

Comment: Not able to give a detailed answer right now but you should put the data obtained from the ABPeoplePicker into some object X and read that object in the cellForRowAtIndexPath.  After the ABPeoplePicker is done, you can call reloadData on the table view to make it show the updated data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use textLabel, not textField. This is, in general, a bad idea. You should provide the proper cell in -tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:. If you only want to adjust one cell, you can use -[UITableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:].

Comment: You are right it is a pretty bad idea. The right approach is as suggested by aBitObvious.